# MicrosoftTeams context not shared between js and js interop in Blazor app - The library has not yet been initialized

Tags: microsoft-teams, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop, microsoft-teams-js

I'm working on a Blazor app that runs embedded inside Microsoft Teams. In order to interact with Teams, we use the [Teams SDK](https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/teams-js@2.5.0) and call it from our C# code using the `IJSRuntime` interface. In order to do anything with the library, we first initialize it by calling `microsoftTeams.app.initialize()` and then continue to use the `microsoftTeams` variable to perform various operations.

Recently, we've run into a requirement where we needed to interact with Teams before interop is available. This meant we are now running a `.js` script on pageload which calls initialize and then performs other operations.

Since `microsoftTeams.app.initialize()` is now called on every page load in the fronted, I expected the library to already be initialized when calling subsequent javascript functions through js interop. Unfortunately, this is not the case. Instead, I get the following error:

`internalAPIs.ts:28 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The library has not yet been initialized`

How can this be? I'd expect the state to be shared and the library to have been initialized. When I save the promise from the init call, I can see its state is fulfilled when the interop `js` runs. Although calling `initialize()` again through interop fixes this issue, initializing the app twice seems to cause issues elsewhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

`Init.js`

```
let teamsInitPromise;

teamsInitPromise = microsoftTeams.app.initialize();
teamsInitPromise.then(() => {
    microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then((context) => {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

`interop.razor`

```
await MicrosoftTeams.InitializeAsync();
var context = await MicrosoftTeams.GetTeamsContextAsync();
culture = context.App.Locale;
```

`interop.js`

```
export function getContextAsync() {
    let scopedPromise = teamsInitPromise; // Promise state "Fulfulled" is shown in developer tools
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then((context) => {
                resolve(context);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Initialize the library, before calling other methods, as per the documentation:
microsoftTeams.initialize()

This is works when running in a Teams app (tab or personal)

Comment: Reference Link-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/appinitialization?view=msteams-client-js-latest

Comment: Hi Sayali, thank you for your response. As mentioned in my question, I do call `microsoftTeams.Initialize()` each time a page is loaded in a javascript script called `init.js` (mentioned above). When I then want to trigger subsequent methods through C#-to-JS interop, the error is returned that the app has not been initialized. Why is the app not initialized still?

Comment: You need to first check using isInitialized() function that library has initialized or not. If not then only you can call the initialize function to initialize library.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/app?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-app-isinitialized